# Flask trying to return a single item from a list returns an error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm have a flask app which lists out my items:

```
@bp.route('/explore')
def explore():
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()))
    return render_template('explore.html', title='Explore', posts=posts.items)
```

What I am trying to do is be able to put the post ID in the URL so then it only returns one specific post, with the ID determined by the URL. This is the code I wrote:

```
@bp.route('/explore/<int:id>')
def item(id):
    posts = Post.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
    return render_template('item.html', posts=posts.items)
```

The error I get here is:

```
 AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'items'
```

When I remove items it doesn't work either. I'm not clear when items would work for the **explore** feature but not for **item**. I've literally copied the working code except trying to just filter to return one ID.

Comment: Doesn't `first_or_404()` return the first item if there is one? In which case, `posts` is actually a single item so would not have a `.items` member. You probably want `post = Post.query...first_or_404()` followed by `return render_template('item.html', posts=[post])` or similar.

Comment: Thank you, would I need the square brackets around [post]?

Comment: You're welcome. Whether you need pass it by itself or as a list of one item depends on what you do with it in `item.html`. From the html template name, I would guess that you are only displaying a single item so there should be fine to pass it without the `[]`.